# Android Firebase notification gives default icon

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have a problem with my Firebase notification icon. Until now it only shows a default android icon when I sent a notification. It looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbIpj.jpg

But that is not even an icon I use. I changed the icons multiple times in "Image assets" but it keeps comming up like this...

What am I doing wrong? Because the only thing I can find on the internet is that people get a gray icon instead of their own.

Comment: add your code and notification icon resolution

Comment: how are you setting the notification icon ?

Comment: mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher); did you added this line in your notification builder? Add your icon as mipmapic_launcher.

Comment: Did you set default notification icon in your manifest? (it is used for the background notifications)
Did you use setSmallIcon(icon) in the FirebaseMessagingService (used for the notifications when your app is opened)?
This is happening for all notifications? When app is in background and foreground also?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages.
     -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
<!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
     notification message.  -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Check this link for more details https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Thanks! i feel like a potato